# SHDocVw for .NET Core projects

Tags: c#, .net-core, shdocvw

I need to move my projects from .Net Framework 4.7.2 to .Net Core platform, and I have difficulties to resolve the problem with code in part of using SHDocVw library.

I have such string of code:

```
using SHDocVw;

...

var list = new ShellWindows().Cast<InternetExplorer>().ToList();
```

and compiler fails on "ShellWindows()" and "InternetExplorer" with next message:

The type or namespace name 'ShellWindows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What Nuget package is required to resolve this problem, either what class and methods can be used instead of current?

Comment: Works just fine as posted in a sample .NET Core 5.0 project.  "compiler fails" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: I'm sorry for low details in my post. Today I've moved to .Net Core 5. All dependencies were resolved, excluding this one. Current message is "The type or namespace name 'ShellWindows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"